# How do you get a node that contains a child node with a given attribute value in an XML document using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I'm working on parsing XML documents using SQL Server 2008. I'm a complete noob and I was wondering if I can get help from you guys.

I have an XML document like the one below and I want to get the "section" node where the "code" node has val=5.

```
<root>
  <section>
    <code val=6 />
    ...
  </section>
  <section>
    <code val=5 />
    ...
  </section>
  <section>
    <code val=4 />
    ...
  </section>
</root>
```

So the result should be:
   `<section>
   <code val=5 />
   ...
   </section>`

I tried doing this, but it didn't work:

`select @xml.query('/root/section') 
   where @xml.value('/root/section/code/@val,'int')= '5'`

I also tried this:
   `select @xml.query('/root/section') 
   where @xml.exist('/root[1]/section[1]/code[@val="1"])= '1'`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
DECLARE @x XML=N'
<root>
  <section atr="A">
    <code val="5" />
  </section>
  <section atr="B">
    <code val="6" />
  </section>
  <section atr="C">
    <code val="5" />
  </section>
</root>';

SELECT  a.b.query('.') AS SectionAsXmlElement,
        a.b.value('@atr','NVARCHAR(50)') AS SectionAtr
FROM    @x.nodes('/root/section[code/@val="5"]') a(b);
```

Results:

```
SectionAsXmlElement                         SectionAtr
------------------------------------------- ----------
<section atr="A"><code val="5" /></section> A
<section atr="C"><code val="5" /></section> C
```

Comment: This worked!! I know no "thank you" comments are allowed here, but I must express my gratitude. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `where` you can apply the constraint in an XPath predicate:

```
@xml.query('/root/section[code/@val=5]')
```

Comment: That only seems to give me: "<code val=5 />" Is there any way of getting "<section> <code val=5 /> ... </section>"? Thanks.